# Find the indicial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do i find the indicial equation to $x^2y''+4xy'+4y=12-12x^2$

I used the frobenius method but got stuck:

$x^2y''+4xy'+4y-12+12x^2=0$

$x^2(y''+12)+4xy'+4y-12=0$

$y''+12+\frac{4y'}{x}+\frac{4y}{x^2}-\frac{12}{x^2}=0$

$y''+\frac{4y'}{x}+\frac{4y}{x^2}+\frac{12x^2-12}{x^2}=0$

let

$y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{k+r}$

$y'=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)a_kx^{k+r-1}$

$y''=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-2}$

then

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4(k+r)a_kx^{k+r-2}+$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4a_kx^{k+r-2}+\frac{12x^2-12}{x^2}=0$

how do i find the co-efficients if they don't depend on each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an inhomogeneous Euler differential equation. One possible textbook procedure is to solve first the associated homogeneous equation
$$x^2y''+4xy'+4y=0\ .\tag{1}$$
The "Ansatz" $y(x)=x^\alpha$ $\>(x>0)$ with a complex parameter $\alpha$ to be determined is successful if
$$x^2\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}+4x\alpha x^{\alpha-1}+4x^\alpha\equiv0\ ,$$
and leads to the *indicial equation*
$$\alpha^2+3\alpha+4=0\ .$$
From its solutions
$$\alpha_{1,2}=-{3\over2}\pm{i\over2}\sqrt{7}$$
we conclude that the general real solution of $(1)$ is given by 
$$y_h(x)=x^{-3/2}\biggl(A\cos\bigl({\sqrt{7}\over2}\log x\bigr)+B\sin\bigl({\sqrt{7}\over2}\log x\bigr)\biggr)\qquad(x>0)\ .$$
In order to obtain a particular solution of the given inhomogeneous equation $(*)$ we introduce the "Ansatz"
$$y_p(x):=ax^2+bx+c$$
with undetermined coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ into $(*)$ and compare coefficients. I found that
$$y_p(x)=-{6\over7}x^2+3$$
does the job. The general real solution of $(*)$ is then given by $$y(x):=y_h(x)+y_p(x)\ .$$

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should first extract the indicial equation by making the D.E homogenous then add the particular solution? Also, I don't understand how you got the indicial equation, how do you determine what kind of "ansatz" fits for $y$ in different situations?

Comment: Oh sorry there, I see you used the method of undertermined co-efficients. So the indicial equation is just the characteristic equation, are they synonymous? if not, why are they so similar, if so, why the need for different names?

Comment: Introducing a new independent variable $t$ such that $x=e^t$ transforms a given Euler differential equation into a differential equation with constant coefficients. It follows that the "algebraic theories" of these two types of differential equations are "isomorphic". The characteristic polynomial of constant coefficient equations appears as "indicial polynomial" in the case of Euler differential equations.